# CI/CD with a GPU cluster

Tags: continuous-integration, cloud

With typical continuous integration environments, you configure an environment capable to execute compilation and test batches (agent, slave..) coordinated by a scheduler (master, server..)

But what if your "client" environment is a Graphics Processing Unit (GPU) cluster used to perform model trainings in different configurations? Is there any difference or would you just for example let the head cluster node incorporate a Jenkins slave? (or Bamboo agent etc)

Comment: You have a GPU cluster at the moment?

Comment: please elaborate your question better - I tend to answer yes

Comment: `But what if your "client" environment is a GPU cluster` Is it a hypothesis or is there a real GPU cluster?

Comment: real, indeed it is

Comment: GPU cluster = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPU_cluster?

Comment: `model trainings in different configurations` Could you give examples?

Comment: Yes. Many configurations means just using different tools/frameworks, or different sets of input data.

Comment: But what exactly is the problem? It's just a resource, it shouldn't matter if it's a GPU cluster or a self-driving car you run tests on. You just have to schedule it's use.

Comment: @JakubKania: this should be an answer IMHO.

Comment: @DanCornilescu To qualify as a full asnwer it would have to be expanded much. That comment is only fishing for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're talking about CI/CD I presume you have the possibility to automate the model trainings in those configurations. Let's call the scripts able to do that `train_model_config_A`, `train_model_config_B`, etc.

Then you could have a wrapper script which checks an environment variable used to select which client environment you desire and invokes the corresponding `train_model_config_<blah>` script. Ideally translating the outcome of the training (whatever that is) into one or more results of the pass/fail type. Then such wrapper script can be integrated in a CI/CD pipeline like a custom test step/stage (or even a build one, if it produces any artifacts you might want to archive). Just like any test executed on a testbed incorporating some non-generic piece of hardware. In other words the CPU cluster makes no real difference.

You might not need to install the slave directly on the GPU cluster if the `train_model_config_<blah>` scripts (and thus the wrapper script as well) can be executed on some other hosts and remotely control the GPUs - you can then have the slave on some other host, leaving the GPU cluster free to only do its stuff.